# Docker/Rails - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir Errno::EACCESS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

> With Docker, I'd like to set up an environment where I can make
>   changes on local files, while the container serves said files.

However, I've been getting the following error, after running `docker-compose run web`:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/src/app/tmp (Errno::EACCES)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `reverse_each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:119:in `block in create_tmp_directories'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:118:in `each'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:118:in `create_tmp_directories'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

The drives are shared on Docker Settings, my Windows Account is Administrator, the PowerShell I'm running these commands at is running as Administrator, and the container's user is root, so I really can't find which permission is it lacking.

I'm using **Docker for Windows** with **Hyper-v** driver, and the following *Dockerfile* and *docker-compose.yml* are within the application's directory:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Official Ubuntu image with Ruby installed
FROM ruby:2.3.0

# Update package lists and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    nodejs \
    sqlite3 \
    libqt4-webkit \
    libqt4-dev \
    xvfb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Define where the application will live inside the image
ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app

# Create the application folder
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME

# Set the working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Add Gemfile and install dependencies
COPY Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

# Copy local folder to work directory
COPY . $APP_HOME
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    privileged: true
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was due to an old failing `docker-machine` from another installation of docker, I forgot to delete it that time and didn't realize that it would still be there on a new installation.

After removing and creating a new `docker-machine`, adding the `virtual switch` [according to official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/), I did not have the permission issues anymore.

Answer (score 1):

@Filipe can you please confirm if your user has write access to the directory "."  on windows? Running as Administrator doesn't guarantee full read/write access to the mounted volumes due to the samba integration.

Comment: Thanks Roberto, not on this issue specifically, but when sharing a volume with the container (on C:/Users) I had to give myself these permissions. Administrator privileges on Windows are very confusing...